# How to do string manipulation in Spark dataframe's columns value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to Spark, i have to perform string manipulation operations and create new column in spark dataframe. I have created UDF functions for string manipulation and due to performance i want to do this without UDF. Following is my code and output. Could please help me to create this in better way?

```
object Demo2 extends Context {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

    val data = Seq(
      ("bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo"),
      ("bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo"),
      ("bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo"),
      ("bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo")
    )
    val df = data.toDF("Key")
    println("Input Dataframe")
    df.show(false)

    //get local_address
    val get_local_address = udf((key: String) => {
      val first_index = key.indexOf(".")
      val tmp_key = key.substring(first_index + 1)
      val last_index = tmp_key.lastIndexOf(".")
      val local_address = tmp_key.substring(0, last_index)
      local_address
    })

    //get address
    val get_address = udf((key: String) => {
      val first_index = key.indexOf(".")
      val tmp_key = key.substring(first_index + 1)
      val last_index1 = tmp_key.lastIndexOf(".")
      val tmp_key1 = tmp_key.substring(0, last_index1)

      val last_index2 = tmp_key1.lastIndexOf(".");
      val first_index1 = tmp_key1.lastIndexOf(".", last_index2 - 1);
      val address = tmp_key1.substring(0, first_index1) + tmp_key1.substring(last_index2)
      address
    })

    val df2 = df
      .withColumn("Local Address", get_local_address(df("Key")))
      .withColumn("Address", get_address(df("Key")))

    println("Output Dataframe")
    df2.show(false)

  }
}

Input Dataframe
+----------------------------------------------+
|Key                                           |
+----------------------------------------------+
|bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo     |
|bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo |
|bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo|
|bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo     |
+----------------------------------------------+

Output Dataframe
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|Key                                           |Local Address            |Address        |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo     |SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune     |SBI.C_1.Pune   |
|bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo |ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune |ICICI.C_2.Pune |
|bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo|Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai|Axis.C_3.Mumbai|
|bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo     |HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune     |HDFC.C_4.Pune  |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: then use the String functions of Spark SQL, or not? like [substring_index](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#substring_index) and others

Answer (score 2):

Since you have fixed sized array, you can structurize them and then concat as required-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |Key
        |bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo
        |bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo
        |bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo
        |bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS1 = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------+
      * |Key                                           |
      * +----------------------------------------------+
      * |bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo     |
      * |bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo |
      * |bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo|
      * |bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo     |
      * +----------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Key: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Derive the columns from the fixed format string column

```
    df1.select($"key", split($"key", "\\.").as("x"))
      .withColumn("bankInfo",
        expr(
          """
            |named_struct('name', element_at(x, 2), 'cust_id', element_at(x, 3),
            | 'branch', element_at(x, 4), 'dist', element_at(x, 5))
          """.stripMargin))
      .select($"key",
        concat_ws(".", $"bankInfo.name", $"bankInfo.cust_id", $"bankInfo.branch", $"bankInfo.dist")
        .as("Local_Address"),
        concat_ws(".", $"bankInfo.name", $"bankInfo.cust_id", $"bankInfo.dist")
        .as("Address"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
      * |key                                           |Local_Address            |Address        |
      * +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
      * |bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo     |SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune     |SBI.C_1.Pune   |
      * |bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo |ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune |ICICI.C_2.Pune |
      * |bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo|Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai|Axis.C_3.Mumbai|
      * |bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo     |HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune     |HDFC.C_4.Pune  |
      * +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
      */
df1.select($"key", split($"key", "\\.").as("x"))
      .withColumn("bankInfo",
        expr("named_struct('name', x[1], 'cust_id', x[2], 'branch', x[3], 'dist', x[4])"))
      .select($"key",
        concat_ws(".", $"bankInfo.name", $"bankInfo.cust_id", $"bankInfo.branch", $"bankInfo.dist")
          .as("Local_Address"),
        concat_ws(".", $"bankInfo.name", $"bankInfo.cust_id", $"bankInfo.dist")
          .as("Address"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
      * |key                                           |Local_Address            |Address        |
      * +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
      * |bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo     |SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune     |SBI.C_1.Pune   |
      * |bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo |ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune |ICICI.C_2.Pune |
      * |bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo|Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai|Axis.C_3.Mumbai|
      * |bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo     |HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune     |HDFC.C_4.Pune  |
      * +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------+
|Key                                           |
+----------------------------------------------+
|bankInfo.SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune.displayInfo     |
|bankInfo.ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune.displayInfo |
|bankInfo.Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai.displayInfo|
|bankInfo.HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune.displayInfo     |
+----------------------------------------------+


scala> val maxLength = df.select(split($"key","\\.").as("keys")).withColumn("length",size($"keys")).select(max($"length").as("length")).map(_.getAs[Int](0)).collect.head
maxLength: Int = 6

scala> val address_except = Seq(0,3,maxLength-1)
address_except: Seq[Int] = List(0, 3, 5)

scala> val local_address_except = Seq(0,maxLength-1)
local_address_except: Seq[Int] = List(0, 5)

scala> def parse(column: Column,indexes:Seq[Int]) = (0 to maxLength).filter(i => !indexes.contains(i)).map(i => column(i)).reduce(concat_ws(".",_,_))
parse: (column: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, indexes: Seq[Int])org.apache.spark.sql.Column

scala> df.select(split($"key","\\.").as("keys")).withColumn("local_address",parse($"keys",local_address_except)).withColumn("address",parse($"keys",address_except)).show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|keys                                                 |local_address            |address        |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|[bankInfo, SBI, C_1, Kothrud, Pune, displayInfo]     |SBI.C_1.Kothrud.Pune     |SBI.C_1.Pune   |
|[bankInfo, ICICI, C_2, TilakRoad, Pune, displayInfo] |ICICI.C_2.TilakRoad.Pune |ICICI.C_2.Pune |
|[bankInfo, Axis, C_3, Santacruz, Mumbai, displayInfo]|Axis.C_3.Santacruz.Mumbai|Axis.C_3.Mumbai|
|[bankInfo, HDFC, C_4, Deccan, Pune, displayInfo]     |HDFC.C_4.Deccan.Pune     |HDFC.C_4.Pune  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```